# Magento 1.9.0.1: product detail page showing white page for all the products?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, white-screen

Product detail page is showing white page for all the products in Magento 1.9.0.1?

Any help would be apppreciated

Comment: please take a look in your webservers error log, it looks like there is a php error occuring.

Comment: @Amy you can check error log

Comment: There is no error in error log.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have error logs turned on? Also make sure in index.php (root folder) you find this part:

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//}
```

...and comment the if statement. 
Also if you can have a look in folder var/log/ for log files. 
After this refresh the page. It's probably because of an fatal error that is not beeing displayed.